# extract data based on time stamp from log file using shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a log file in which data keeps on appending depends on server stop and start . Now i want to find out the downtime of the server ie time in which it is not available .

Main issue here is there are serveral line of stopping and starting and so need to find out the stop server line and then the next line for start of server and then the time diff .

Can some one please help me with this ?

I will paste the part of the log here .
 pattern is :`Stopping Container` and `Started Module cloud.services.CloudInstance`

```
[2016-03-02 14:25:09,864 (INFO )][Thread-1]  Wed Mar 02 14:25:09 UTC 2016 Stopping Container <main>...
[2016-03-02 14:25:09,864 (INFO )][Thread-1]  Wed Mar 02 14:25:09 UTC 2016 Stopping WebServer...
[2016-03-02 14:25:09,872 (ERROR)][Thread-1]  [Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner - javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
[2016-03-02 14:25:09,872 (ERROR)][Thread-1]  [Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{//}
[2016-03-02 14:25:10,009 (ERROR)][Thread-1]  [Thread-1] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool - 103 threads could not be stopped

-----

[2016-03-02 10:34:04,628 (ERROR)][main]  [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9192
[2016-03-02 10:34:04,628 (INFO )][main]
Started Module cloud.services.CloudInstance@6232a3cd
```

Thanks in Advance ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep will fetch the data based on pattern matching

```
grep 'Stopping Container' server.log >stoptimings.txt
grep 'Started Module cloud.services.CloudInstance' server.log >starttimings.txt
```

#### Edit1:

You can use awk (not a one liner) like below

```
cat stoptimings.txt | awk '
BEGIN{
FS="["
}
{
  curTime=substr($2,12,8)
  m=split(curTime,t,":")
  n=split(prevTime,w,":")
  firstTime= (t[1]*3600) + (t[2]*60) + t[3]
  secondTime= (w[1]*3600) + (w[2]*60) + w[3]
  diffTime=(firstTime - secondTime)
  prevTime=curTime
  printf("%s|%s|%s|%s\n",curTime,firstTime,secondTime,diffTime)
}'
```

diff time will be printed in seconds. you can use below code to get the difference in minutes

```
diffTime=(firstTime - secondTime) / 60
```

Comment: Thanks ,but the main issue here is there are several such lines with the diff time stamp , i want to take consecutive such lines and calculate the time difference ,

Comment: @Piyush, That's intersting ..I have updated my answer.

Comment: I think i am not clear eith the requirement , so after filter i will have a log file which look like this

[2016-03-02 10:33:44,596 (INFO )][Thread-1]  Wed Mar 02 10:33:44 UTC 2016 Stopping Container <main>...
[2016-03-03 04:48:07,983 (INFO )][Thread-1]  Thu Mar 03 04:48:07 UTC 2016 Stopping Container <main>…


[2016-03-02 10:34:04,631 (INFO )][main]  Wed Mar 02 10:34:04 UTC 2016 [main] [INFO] Server Started
[2016-03-02 14:27:54,010 (INFO )][main]  Wed Mar 02 14:27:54 UTC 2016 [main] [INFO] Server Started

now i have to find out the time diff between first stop and first start and so on ..

Comment: @Piyush, does your `grep` output a oneliner ?Are you getting the data in single line or multiple lines ?

Comment: @Piyush, if above answer is not working, then paste the output of this command `grep 'Stopping Container' server.log | head -3` . This will help us to provide appropriate solution.

Comment: comment section won't format the content. Can you update the question. Click on 'edit' link & paste the content of your file , current output, errors if any ..